# Disabling permalinks on Tumblr posts

Tags: tumblr

I have a photo collage-style blog on Tumblr. I'm trying to make some of the images essentially function like buttons. I can set a click-thru link, but when you click the image you get the permalink page and then you have to click it again to actually go through to the link. I would like to eliminate the permalink step, so when the picture is clicked it goes straight through to the link. Help?